# Was the TRS-80 Model 1 ever actually sold new with that name?

Tags: history, trs-80

When Tandy introduced the TRS-80, the computer we know now as the "Model 1" or Model I" was simply called the **TRS-80**. No "Model" designation was necessary. The early releases were as follows:

1. TRS-80, August 1977
2. TRS-80 Model II, October 1979 (expensive model for business market)
3. TRS-80 Model III, July 1980 (home computer successor to original TRS-80)
4. TRS-80 Model 4, April 1983 (successor to the Model III)

One assumes the original computer was given and marketed with a distinguishing name once the Model II began to be marketed. Was it:

1. TRS-80 Model I (Roman numeral to match the Model II)
2. TRS-80 Model 1 (Arabic for simplicity, and make the Model II name seem "classy")
3. Tandy never actually gave the original an official, distinguishing name.

I have searched, and have not been able to find an authoritative answer. Some sites use Arabic, some Roman numerals. If there was a distinguishing name given, would someone please post a picture of the box with that name, or perhaps an official Tandy advertisement using that name? (Without a picture, it didn't happen! ) A link would be useful as well.

Comment: Like the old fake headline "World War I ended" It wasn't I until there was a II.

Answer (score 14):

I've gathered some pictures. Here is an early USA advert.

[image: USA introductory ad for TRS-80]

Note that it is never referred to as a "Model 1" or "Model I". It's just a "TRS-80".

Here is a later USA ad, after the Model II was released.
[image: USA TRS-80 ad after Model II released]

Note that the price has gone down, but there is no indication that they have extended the name for the original model. The new Model II is specifically called out though. (The "Level I" refers to the low-end BASIC sold with the cheapest system.)

Here is a later ad from the UK.  It also came after the Model II was released.
[image]

Both the Model I and Model II names are specifically called out, in addition to the two Model I systems for Level I BASIC and Level II BASIC.

Tentatively these ads indicate that the original machine was publicly referred to as the "Model I" in the UK. The [catalog](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/catalogs_extra/1979_rsc-03_small/) Raffzahn mentions is for the USA (I looked it up), so at least in brochures, Tandy would refer to the "Model I" after the Model II came out. The middle image suggests Tandy did not feel it necessary to use the Model I designater in USA ads.

Answer (score 12):

Radio Shack product names not infrequently differed from country to
country, even if only subtly. This answer covers only U.S. naming.

But yes, the TRS-80 Model I was sold new under that name and always
used the Roman numeral. This happened only after the Model II was
released, and the full name including "Model I" was not used
consistently.

### 1979

[image: 1979 back page]
[image: 1979 p.79]

In their U.S. catalogs through 1979, before the introduction of the
Model II, the Model I was always referred to only as the
"TRS-80™ computer." See, for example, the [back page](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/html/1979/h176.html) and
[page 79](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/html/1979/h079.html) of the 1979 catalog, the latter headlined "The
Breakthrough Radio Shack TRS-80™ Computer!"

### 1980

[image: 1980 back page]
[image: 1980 page 170]
[image: 1980 page 174]
[image: 1980 page 175]

With the introduction of the Model II, Radio Shack starts using the
term "Model I" sometimes, but not always, and usually only when a
Model II is nearby.

The [back page](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/html/1980/h176.html) of the 1980 catalog has an inset headlined
"New Low Price on Model I." However, at the computer section of the
catalog starts on [page 170](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/html/1980/h170.html) with the Model I but always
called simply the "TRS-80™ Computer" or "TRS-80."

This continues through the next three pages until we get to printers
on [page 174](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/html/1980/h174.html), where the page is headlined "Add Printed Output
to Your Model I or II TRS-80." Yet even there the product lines have
things like "Cable for TRS-80 Expansion Interface" listed next to
"Cable for TRS-80 Model II." (Arguably, that's fine because there was
no Expansion Interface for the Model II, only the Model I.)

Even on [page 175](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/html/1980/h175.html), where the catalog moves on to the Model
II, the headline is "Meet the TRS-80's Big Brother!" though it
eventually goes on to use "Model I" in the text, mostly:

> ...whose capabilities *begin* where the TRS-80 Model I approaches
>   upper limits. Model II operates at twice Model I's speed, but it's
>   not intended to replace — or compete with — the original TRS-80.

### 1981

[image: 1981 back cover]
[image: 1981 page 169]
[image: 1981 page 170]
[image: 1981 page 171]

By 1981 the term "TRS-80" refers to Radio Shack's entire line of
computers, not just the Model III but also the CoCo and the Pocket
Computer (PoCo?), all of which were introduced that year. The
[back cover](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/html/1981/h176.html) of the 1981 catalog has no reference at all to
the Model I, but displays pictures and descriptions of the "TRS-80
Color Computer,", "TRS-80 Model III" and "TRS-80 Pocket Computer"
under the headline "Radio Shack Introduces a Whole New World of
*Affordable* TRS-80™ Computer Systems."

The computer section of the catalog starts on [page 169](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/html/1981/h169.html) with
a page devoted entirely to the Model I, but the headline "The
Amazingly Expandable TRS-80™." Below this, however, the product
description uses "TRS-80 Model I" (twice). Usage varies throughout the
page.

The next page, [page 170](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/html/1981/h170.html), introduces the successor to the
Model I, headlined "The New Model III." The description compares it
with "Model I," and "Model III" is used as a qualifier throughout on
accessories such as disk drives that work only on the Model III.

[Page 171](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/html/1981/h171.html) is headlined "TRS-80 Model I & III Software," and
stating that "All programs will work on Model I or Model III unless
otherwise noted." Just a few items have "Mod I only" beside them.

And the rest goes on in that vein.

### 1982

[image: 1982 page 172]

By 1982 the Model I itself is no longer in the catalog, though there
is a small section of "TRS-80 Model I Accessories" on [page
172](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/html/1982/h172.html). The software page still offers "The Growing Library of
TRS-80 Model I & III Software," but "Mod I only" software is gone.

Answer (score 4):

I did browse some of my racks and found that throughout all Tandy Computer Catalogues, starting with RCS-3 in 1979 ([Page 6](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/html/catalogs_extra/1979_rsc-03/h006.html)) the original TRS-80 was called `TRS-80 Model I` (Roman Numeral). Before that it was just called the `TRS-80 (system)` ([RCS-1, 1977](http://www.radioshackcatalogs.com/html/catalogs_extra/1977_rsc-01/h005.html))

But in original Tandy manuals and documentations I did find many spellings as `TRS-80 Model 1`. So it seems as if they did keep the `Model I` seplling throughout all advertisement, but not over all.

Similar BTW for the early distinction between Level 1/2 and I/II BASIC.

Comment: I've been researching too. So far, it seems that in Britain the "Model I" designation was used. In the USA, though, I have found no evidence that "Model I" or "Model 1" was ever an official descriptor. Nor have I seen any images of the computer itself where the front plate or keyboard used anything other than "TRS-80". I've gathered some images, will post in a while. Would you and @wizzwizz4 like to meet in chat?

Comment: From which country or countries were these catalogues? (Radio Shack often slightly changed product names from country to country.)

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Mine are US issues. I got them from the US. A few back then, but most I bought way later when digging thru HAM flea markets in California :)) In fact, I don't have any German Tandy leaflets. Tandy had shops in Germany only for a very brief period in the early 80s, way before I started to collect materials.